# Adding X-Y offsets to data points

Tags: python, altair

I'm looking for a way to specify an X-Y offset to plotted data points. I'm just getting into Altair, so please bear with me.

The situation: I have a dataset recording daily measurements for 30 people. Every person can register several different types of measurements every day.

Example dataset & plot, with 2 people and 2 measurement types:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"date": pd.to_datetime(pd.date_range("2019-12-01", periods=5).repeat(4)), 
        "person": pd.np.tile(["Bob", "Amy"], 10), 
        "measurement_type": pd.np.tile(["score_a", "score_a", "score_b", "score_b"], 5), 
        "value": 20.0*np.random.random(size=20)})

import altair as alt

alt.Chart(df, width=600, height=100) \
            .mark_circle(size=150) \
            .encode(x = "date",
                    y = "person",
                    color = alt.Color("value"))
```

This gives me this graph:
[image: Two measurement types on top of each other...]

In the example above, the 2 measurement types are plotted on top of each other. I would like to add an offset to the circles depending on the "measurement_type" column, so that they can all be made visible around the date-person location in the graph.

Here's a mockup of what I want to achieve:
[image: Non-blocking measurement types!]

I've been searching the docs but haven't figured out how to do this - been experimenting with the "stack" option, with the `dx` and `dy` options, ...
I have a feeling this should just be another encoding channel (`offset` or alike), but that doesn't exist.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no concept of an offset encoding in Altair, so the best approach to this will be to combine a column encoding with a y encoding, similar to the [Grouped Bar Chart](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/grouped_bar_chart.html) example in Altair's documentation:

```
alt.Chart(df,
    width=600, height=100
).mark_circle(
    size=150
).encode(
    x = "date",
    row='person',
    y = "measurement_type",
    color = alt.Color("value")
)
```

[image]

You can then fine-tune the look of the result using standard [chart configuration](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/configuration.html) settings:

```
alt.Chart(df,
    width=600, height=alt.Step(25)
).mark_circle(
    size=150
).encode(
    x = "date",
    row='person',
    y = alt.Y("measurement_type", title=None),
    color = alt.Color("value")
).configure_facet(
    spacing=10
).configure_view(
    strokeOpacity=0
)
```

[image]

Comment: OK, that indeed looks like the best solution.

Would an offset encoding be something to include in the roadmap?

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know what result you are getting up until know, but maybe write a function whith parameters like`def chart(DotsOnXAxis, FirstDotsOnYAxis, SecondDotsOnYAxis, OffsetAmount)`
and then put those variables on the right place.

If you want an offset with the dots maybe put in a system like: `SecondDotsOnYAxis = FirstDotsOnYAxis + OffsetAmount`